# Rogue reforge for pve/pvp

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am wondering which is the best reforging for rogue on pve gear, and which is on pvp gear. I know for pve first should be hit rating to 8% and then the rest but I don't know if this applies to pvp as well.

What I ask for is for subtetly 8/2/31 for pvp and combat for pve. Also, I'm not even sure reforging makes sense if you have vicious set for pvp.

Well, this is pretty straight-forward question so any suggestions are appreciated. Also, I'm really not interested in anything else(glyph,builds,poisons etc) but the reforging matter. Thanks.

My references are from [wowpopular](http://www.wowpopular.com/PvP/Reforges/Rogue/Subtlety),[maxdps](http://maxdps.com/rogue/combat.php),[pverogues](http://www.pverogues.com/cataclysm/reforging-your-gear-as-a-rogue/).

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you can follow these priorities:

PVP(Sub): 5% Melee Hit > Crit > Haste > Mastery > Expertise
PVE(Combat): 8% Melee Hit > Expertise (26) > Haste > Mastery > Hit(up to 27%) > Crit

You can look for suggestions on places like [Elitist Jerks](http://elitistjerks.com/f78/) then try various setups on online tools like [Ask Mr. Robot](http://www.askmrrobot.com/wow/gear)

Anyway you don't need 8% hit for PvP, the hit cap against other players is 5%. Take a look at [this guide](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/1869217043) on the official forums for a lot of useful suggestions for PvP, regarding not only equip and spec, but also glyphs and abilities priority.

For PvE you can read [this other guide](http://elitistjerks.com/f78/t111329-combat_guide_cata_12_01_2011_a/) on the aforementioned Elitist Jerks forum.

Comment: your expertise should take priority after hit% in both specs until you hit 20/20(26/26 for pve) IMO. You don't want any kidney shots being dodged!